# How to add my app to a specific repository branch? Or how to start creating a app inside a new branch?

Tags: git, android-studio

I have to clone a repository in which there is only a postman collection and a readme, do a checkout and develop an app in this new brach before a do pull request. How do I create the app in this branch using android studio? Or how do I make the app first and move it to my branch?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new branch by:

```
Git branch "name of the branch"
```

and switch to a specific branch by :

```
Git checkout "name of the branch"
```

Also you can check which branch you are currently on it, simply by :

```
git branch
```

When you commit your change locally now you can push it to remote repository in the branch which created locally by you. By do so a branch will created in the remote repository.

Comment: Yes, but I have two spefic scenarios I have to handle: 1) I made the app to practice in my own repository (github). How do I move it to to this branch I've just created in the other repositiory? 2) If I clone a repository (only with a readme and a postman collection) and make a new branch in it, how do I start making my app inside of it?

Comment: 1)After cloning the app, change the remote repository url to new one and then push the app to it. 2)I don't understand what you mean?